# Is there a way to link excel sheet to auto add and delete data

Tags: excel, excel-formula, spreadsheet, excel-tables

I have an excel workbook in that I have 2 sheets with one sheet having all the data. I want to link the 2 sheets so that whenever I update the main sheet the other sheet also gets reflected. I know one way to use paste link option but in that if I add data to original sheet the linked sheet data is not getting reflected.
These are my data in sheets:

```
sheet1
Name      | location | number
Mr Taker  | xys      | 12345585
Mr senior | ab       | 124953
Mr hello  | abcd     | 384752
```

If anyone know how to do it kindly help. Thanks in Advance

Comment: Check under Options > Formulas and check if 'Workbook Calculations' is set to Automatic or Manual.  If Manual then in order for the updates to occur you would need to calculate manually to update using F9 or Shift+F9 or you could change the setting to Automatic

Comment: Workbook Calculations is set to Automatic only.

Comment: By "update" do you mean "enter data manually"? If yes, select the first sheet, hold down the Control key and click on the name of the second sheet and that's it: each key typed will be recorded in both sheets. Can you explain why you want this?

Comment: I mean linked sheet to be updated automatically when the original sheet is updated (i.e.) if I add any new name to the sheet1 the sheet2 should also reflect the same